# How to replace a row in pandas with multiple rows after applying a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-processing, data-processing

I have a pandas dataframe that contains only one column which contains a string. I want to apply a function to each row that will split the string by sentence and replace that row with rows generated from the function.

Example dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["A sentence. Another sentence. More sentences here.", "Another line of text"])
```

Output of `df.head()`:

```
                                                   0
0  A sentence. Another sentence. More sentences h...
1                               Another line of text
```

I have tried using `apply()` method as follows:

```py
def get_sentence(row):
    return pd.DataFrame(re.split('\.', row[0]))
df.apply(get_sentence, axis=1)
```

But then `df.head()` gives:

```
0                          0
0            A sentenc...
1                            0
0  Another line of text
```

I want the output as:

```
                     0
0            A sentence
1      Another sentence
2   More sentences here
3  Another line of text
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Maybe `df[0].str.split(r'\.(?!$)').explode().reset_index()`?

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df[0].str.split(r'\.(?!$)').explode().reset_index(drop=True).str.rstrip('.')
```

Output:

```
0               A sentence
1         Another sentence
2     More sentences here
3     Another line of text
```

The `\.(?!$)` regex matches a dot not at the end of the string. The `.explode()` splits the results across rows and the `.reset_index(drop=True)` resets the indices. `.str.rstrip('.')` will remove  trailing dots.

You can also use `Series.str.findall` version:

```py
>>> df[0].str.findall(r'[^.]+').explode().reset_index(drop=True)
0              A sentence
1        Another sentence
2     More sentences here
3    Another line of text
```

where `[^.]+` matches any one or more chars other than `.` char.

Comment: In the expected outcome, 3rd row doesn't have a dot. What's the regex to get rid of that as well?

Comment: @NewbieAF `.str.rstrip('.')` will solve it. Or, `.findall(r'[^.]+')` can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all your strings to a 'flat' list, and build a new DataFrame or Series of that.

```
pd.DataFrame([item for sublist in list(df[0].str.split('.')) for item in sublist])
```

Be careful though. If you have elements that only consist of a '.', this will result in weird/blank new rows.